# Move and rename MainPage.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store

I am developing a Windows Store project, and I wish to move MainPage.xaml into a folder called Views. After that I want to rename it. I already attempted doing this, but I ended up breaking it (InitializeComponent could not find a definition).

How can I move and rename the page properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems that the MainPage type is hard-coded in the auto-generated code.

look at [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/ilich/archive/2013/05/06/how-to-change-windows-store-apprsquos-start-page.aspx) to get information on how to change it.

Let's say you renamed it to `MyView.xaml`, and moved it to Views folder.

You will probably want (not necessary) to also:

```
1. add ".Views" to the namespace in MyView.xaml.cs
2. add ".Views." to the x:Class tag in MyView.xaml
```

Now open `App.cs`, and locate the following line

```
if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
{
     ....
}
```

change `MainPage` to reference your new page name.

Comment: App.xaml does not contain a StartupUri code. I assume I should add it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply make sure to keep the namespaces between the code behind and the xaml synchronized:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace YourNameSpace.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNameSpace.Views.MainPage"
             ....>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: How about the code for changing which page to display on start-up?

Comment: In the `App.xamls.cs` in the `OnLaunched` method there is something like: `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage))`; make sure that is pointing to the right MainPage.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note: It's a little different on Windows Phone: the startup page is defined in the `DefaultTask` section of the `WMAppManifest.xml` file:

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
</Tasks>
```